# User can re-authenticate

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In drupal once a user authenticated session is started, and until that session is over, the user won't have to re-authenticate. But in my site users can re-authenticate. And there is no any error message. Does it possible to happen? And how can I check user has already logged and has session?

I tried to get all logged users but I am not shure it will work:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT u.uid, u.name FROM {sessions} s INNER JOIN {users} u ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.uid != 0')->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_is_anonymous()
```

will tell you if the current user is logged or not

another way would be to use global $user

```
global $user;
if($user->uid) 
  print('logged in');
else 
  print('logged out');
```

However this is not normal that a logged user can access user/login again.  Drupal would normally redirect to the user's account page.